# Postgres Audit Table

Tags: postgresql, audit

Is it good practice to use a table in Postgres as an audit log for login events? The database has other tables like users, posts etc. If the backend receives a failed login, it would insert into the audit table the timestamp, username, action type (in this case failed).

Comment: Yes, I believe everyone does, but you can use another kind of data store like file system or serial database, but there's no problem

Comment: @Krismorte i thought about using a table so i can easily access the data whenever i need it

Comment: Actually one of the microservices strategies is called event sourcing and save all the changes in a single table https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html